# Xvnc4 started from xinetd only displays empty gray X screen

Tags: gnome, vnc, inetd

I'm attempting to setup an Ubuntu 10.10 box so that anyone can connect to port 5900 and be greeted by the gdm login manager. To do so, I added a vnc entry in /etc/services and I am starting Xvnc4 using this xinetd config file:

```
service vnc
{
  protocol = tcp
  socket_type = stream
  wait = no
  user = nobody
  server = /usr/bin/Xvnc
  server_args = -geometry 1000x700 -depth 24 -broadcast -inetd -once -securitytypes None
}
```

This kind of works...I can start multiple sessions all to port 5900, and I get an X screen. The problem is that I only get an empty, gray X screen with no applications started.

I know when you run vncserver from the command line it will look to your ~/.vnc/ directory for your passwd and xstartup files, and I think what I want to do is put "gnome-session" into the xstart file. However, which xstartup file? The running user is "nobody" who obviously doesn't have a ~/.vnc/ directory. I tried a /root/.vnc/xstartup file and a ~scott/.vnc/xstartup file and it doesn't look like they were even read.

I changed the xinetd vnc service so that it would "strace" Xvnc4. I looked thru all the "open" lines and didn't get a clue as to what file it was trying to read for xstart.

Can anyone help? I just want a terminal server where the user is presented with a gdm login screen.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to remove the `gray X` screen, you may need to create the `password` and add `xstartup` profile for each of the user accounts.

1) to create vnserver password, switch the account or log in as the specific user

Switch account

```
su - **user_name**
```

Setup vnc user password

```
vncserver
```

out put will be like this prompting for a vnc password..

```
You will require a password to access your desktops.

Password:
Verify:

xauth:  file /home/**user_name**/.Xauthority does not exist
New 'server1:1 (**user_name**)' desktop is server1:1
Creating default startup script /home/**user_name**/.vnc/xstartup
Starting applications specified in /home/**user_name**/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/**user_name**/.vnc/server1:1.log
```

2) Create the xstartup profile

```
vim /home/test1/.vnc/xstartup


and add
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
startxfce4 &

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
```

3) reboot server

```
sudo reboot
```

Reference: You may have a look here for the full installation 
http://rupeshkushwaha.blogspot.sg/2017/11/vnc-server-installation-and.html

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](http://linuxreviews.org/howtos/xvnc/#toc6) you need to make sure that GDM uses XDCMP & that localhost is allowed to make XDCMP calls to itself...

Comment: In Ubuntu 10.10, there is no program called "gdmconfig", and there is no longer an "/etc/gdm/gdm.conf".

Comment: Ah, ok. Sorry about that, I should've assumed that you knew how to use google ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have 10.10 so I can't test. My bad.

Comment: Seems GDM on 10.10 doesn't even allow XDCMP any more, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MaverickMeerkat/ReleaseNotes

Answer (score 0):

I finally gave up on this, started fresh from a snapshot of my system, and installed xrdp and vnc4server. Worked right out of the box. Very frustrating. I will be trying VNC again when 11.04 comes out.